# Filter information and custom repository with Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

From GET parameters, I want to get information from my entities.

In my view I created a form with 3 selects (not multiple ones), like this:

http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1393414663.png

If I filter only by user I got this in the url: **?category=0&user=6&status=0**

I'll have to handle the 0 values...

This form used to filter my tasks.

This is a part of my action in my controller:

```
if($request->query->has('user')) {
    $category_id = $request->query->get('category');
    $user_id = $request->query->get('user');
    $status_id = $request->query->get('status');

    // A little test to see if it works.
    echo $category_id . '<br>' . $user_id . '<br>' . $status_id;

    // I will pass these variables to a repository
    $tasks = $em->getRepository('LanCrmBundle:Task')->findFiltered($category_id, $user_id, $status_id);
} else {
    $tasks = $em->getRepository('LanCrmBundle:Task')->findAll();
}
```

I create a repository with this method:

```
public function findFiltered($category_id, $user_id, $status_id)
{
    /**
    * Get filtered tasks.
    *
    * Get only title, priority, created_at, category_id, user_id and status_id fields (optimization)
    *
    * Where field category_id = $category_id unless $category_id is smaller than 1 (not secure enough)
    * Where field user_id = $user_id unless $user_id is smaller than 1 (not secure enough)
    * Where field status_id = $status_id unless $status_id is smaller than 1 (not secure enough)
    * Should I do these tests here or in the controller?
    */
}
```

How to do this query ? Do you have any other elegant suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
public function findFiltered($category_id, $user_id, $status_id)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');

    if(!empty($category_id) && is_numeric($category_id)) {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere('t.category = :category')->setParameter('category', $category_id);
    }

    if(!empty($user_id) && is_numeric($user_id)) {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere('t.user = :user')->setParameter('user', $user_id);
    }

    if(!empty($status_id) && is_numeric($status_id)) {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere('t.status = :status')->setParameter('status', $status_id);
    }

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

Comment: Thanks it works well. I just realized that this is not the status of the task but the status of the project that owns the task. How can I do that? I have a project property in my Task entity and my Project entity has a status property (related to ProjectStatus entity).